# error: no matching function for call to 'Rectangle::Rectangle()'

Tags: c++, function, matching

I do not understand why this program is not working. I'm new to C++, switching after three years of Java. I thought the error messages in Java made no sense but the errors I've been getting in C++ have been just straight gibberish. This is one I can actually understand.

Anyway so I have a program that has a Rectangle and Square Class. The square class inherits from the rectangle class. All my classes are all in different files.

================================(main)

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Rectangle.h"
#include "Square.h"

using namespace std;

    int main(){

        Square sq;

    }//end main
```

================================(Rectangle.h)

```
#ifndef RECTANGLE_H
#define RECTANGLE_H

class Rectangle{

    public:

        Rectangle (int, int);

        void setLength (int);

        void setWidth (int);

        int getLength ();

        int getWidth ();

        int getArea ();

    private:

         int length;
         int width;

};

#endif // RECTANGLE_H
```

=================================(Rectangle.cpp)

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Rectangle.h"
#include "Square.h"

using namespace std;

    Rectangle :: Rectangle (int len, int wid){
        length = len;
        width = wid;
    }//end constructor

    void Rectangle :: setLength (int l){
        length = l;
    }//end setLength

    void Rectangle :: setWidth (int w){
        width = w;
    }//end setWidth

    int Rectangle :: getLength (){
        return length;
    }//end getLength

    int Rectangle :: getWidth (){
        return width;
    }//end getWidth

    int Rectangle :: getArea (){
        return length * width;
    }//end getArea
```

========================================(Square.h)

```
#ifndef SQUARE_H
#define SQUARE_H

class Square : public Rectangle
{

    public:
        Square();

};

#endif // SQUARE_H
```

====================================(Square.cpp)

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Rectangle.h"
#include "Square.h"

using namespace std;

    Square :: Square {

        //super :: Square(4, 3);
        cout << "This is bullshit";

    };
```

=======================================================

Comment: C++ doesn't have a `super` keyword. It uses constructor initialization lists to initialize things (unless you count in-class member initialization, introduced in C++11).

Comment: IMPORTANT NOTE: You are using OOP wrong. You just demonstrated a variant of the circle-ellipse-problem: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle-ellipse_problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass parent constructor parameters via initialization list...

For example, if default Rectangle parameters are (4, 3):

```
Square :: Square( )
  : Rectangle(4, 3) 
{
   //super :: Square(4, 3);
   cout << "This is bullshit";
}
```

Or, it will be better:

```
Square :: Square(int len, int wid)
  : Rectangle(len, wid) 
{
}
```

And in header file:

```
class Square : public Rectangle
{
    public:
        Square(int len=4, int width=3);
};
```

Comment: holy crap thank you so much dude. Ive been at this for almost a week now. =)

Answer (score 2):

`Square sq;`

This will call the default constructor of `Square` which will first call the default constructor of the base class `Rectangle`. A default constructor is a constructor that has no parameters or if it has parameters, *all* parameters have default values. C++ compiler would provide you one default constructor if you have not defined a constructor. Since you have defined a constructor `Rectangle (int, int)`, compiler will not supply a default constructor. That is the reason for the error.

Solution is to provide a default constructor for `Rectangle` class by defining a constructor which takes no parameters `Rectangle()` or give default values to the parameters of the existing constructor, say `Rectangle(int x=10, int y=20)`